# Syntax error: Operator expected in my code

Tags: prolog

I am a beginner at Prolog so I got this piece of code but I don't understand why it doesn't work

```
max([Max],Max).
max([H1,H2|T],Max):- H1 > H2, max([H1|T],Max).
max([H1,H2|T],Max):- H1 < H2, max([H2|T],Max).

pozitia([X|_], X, 1).
pozitia([_|Y], X, I) :- pozitia(Y, X, I2), I is I2 + 1.

questions

max([1,2,3,4,5,7,2],X).
pozitia([1,2,3,4,5,3,2,1,1,2,3,4], 4, Pozitia).
```

The error I got is `Syntax error: Operator expected`.

I don't understand why!

Comment: i am using swi prolog online

Answer (score 0):

Your program is good! Just remove `questions` line, and then write your queries in the query window.

So your program should just be

```
max([Max],Max).
max([H1,H2|T],Max):- H1 > H2, max([H1|T],Max).
max([H1,H2|T],Max):- H1 < H2, max([H2|T],Max).

pozitia([X|_], X, 1).
pozitia([_|Y], X, I) :- pozitia(Y, X, I2), I is I2 + 1.
```

And then in query window you write

```
max([1,2,3,4,5,7,2],X), pozitia([1,2,3,4,5,3,2,1,1,2,3,4], 4, Pozitia).
```

Good luck!

[image]